# Traversing through a class object list and printing it out

Tags: c++

I have a class object structure as shown below. Here place names are objects of class X and bank names are objects of class Y.

```
<MidWest>
   <Independent Bank Of MidWest/>
   <Midland Bank Of America/>
   <Texas>
      <Bank Of America/>
      <Chase Bank/>
      <Wells Fargo/>
      <Austin>
         <Supereme National Bank/>
         <Master Chanse Bank/>
         <Austin East>
            <National Bank Of Austin/>
            <Federal Bank/>
         </Austin East>
      </Austin>
    </Texas>
   <Arizona></Arizona>
   <Kansas>
      <Federal Credit Union/>
      <Kansas State Bank/>
      <Wichita>
         <State Bank of Kansas/>
         <Wichita Credit Union/>
      </Wichita>
   </Kansas>
   <Missouri>
      <Bank of St Louis/>
   </Missouri>
   <Kentucky></Kentucky>
   <Iowa></Iowa>
</MidWest>
```

What I want to do is, traverse from the parent (**MidWest**) object and go through each child element and print it out. The trick here is, there can be multiple class X objects inside a class X object itself.

I couldn't come up with a smart logic that will loop through and find all child elements and print it out. The above object structure is just an example. In my application I could get any combination of places and banks and this logic should be smart enough to traverse from ROOT parent down to each child element.

Comment: Google for "recursion". Warning: many people find it a bit difficult to understand the first few (dozen) times they read about it.

Comment: Where the code that you tried to write, and what problem are you having with it? Or, are you asking for someone else to write your code for you?

Comment: You need a data structure, or two. What are you using? Show your code.

Comment: How do you distinguish between locations and banks? Also this format appears to be ad hoc and not valid XML. Is that your intention?